# Cannot convert 'int (*)[size]' to 'int**'

Tags: array, functions

Analyzing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188355/cannot-convert-int-size-to-int) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329107/passing-a-pointer-representing-a-2d-array-to-a-function-in-c) answers under Arduino, which should be the proper way to pass a 2D array into a function?

The function should be applicable to different sizes of 2D arrays.

```
// NOT COMPILING EXAMPLE
void f(int** x,const int m, const int n){
// access x as x[0][0], x[0][1], etc...
}

void main{}{
    int x1[16][128];
    f(x1,16,128);
    int x2[64][16];
    f(x2,64,16);
}
```

Comment: the compiler must know the second dimension's size. one option is `void f(int x[][128],const int m){`

Comment: I'd rather use one dimensional array. It's not so hard to transform two dimensional indexes to one dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the prototype of `f` and the usage pattern for its `x`
argument, the function expects this argument to be a pointer to the
first element of an array of pointers to the first elements of arrays of
`int`. However, the matrix in `main()` is defined as an array of arrays
of `int`. If you try to pass this to a function, the matrix will decay
into a pointer to an array of `int`. That's not what you want.

If you want both dimensions of the matrix to be variable, the only
simple solution I see is to build an extra array of pointers (pointing
to the matrix rows) and pass *that array* to the function

```cpp
int main() {
    int x[16][128];

    // Build an array of pointers to rows.
    int *px[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        px[i] = x[i];

    f(px, 16, 128);
}
```

For more information on this, see the section [Arrays and Pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) in
the C FAQ, and more specifically the questions 6.16 (*How can I
dynamically allocate a multidimensional array?*) and 6.19 (*How do I write
functions which accept two-dimensional arrays when the width is not
known at compile time?*).